# Change the background color of posts

Tags: wordpress

How is it possible to change the background color of `posts` when they are available with the button "read more"? I refer read more because when user clicks the button goes to the full page of post and this is not the background color I want to change. Is there any easy way to make it in `wordpress`?

[example post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTo7A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just CSS:

```
.blog_holder article {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot please and point to what area you are trying to change?

Comment: yes of course. I updated my question with a screen shoot. Please see that in post object c post behind the background is white. This is what I try to change